# I got his code with no errors for converting celsius and fahrenheit, but the answers are wrong

Tags: c#

```
 class conv
{

    public double input;
    public double value;
    public double ctf()
    {
        value = (9.0 / 5.0) * input + 32;
        return value;
    }
    public double ftc()
    {
        value = (5.0 / 9.0) * (input - 32);
        return value;
    }
}
```

//two classes are needed. for example, when I enter 100 and try to convert from celsius to fahrenheit, the answer is 32, and it's -17.7777777 when from fahrenheit to celsius!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    double input = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    try
    {

        conv cf = new conv();


        if (comboBox1.Text == "celsius to fahrenheit")
        {
            cf.ctf();
            label3.Text = cf.value.ToString();
        }
        else if (comboBox1.Text == "fahrenheit to celsius")
        {
            cf.ftc();
            label3.Text = cf.value.ToString();

}
```

Answer (score 8):

You're not setting `input` field value at all!

```
conv cf = new conv();

// set cf.input value
cf.input = input;
```

***Update***: But to be honest, your code has really poor quality. I would go with static methods instead of instance ones:

```
public static class TemperatureConverter
{
    public static double ToFahrenheit(double celsius)
    {
        return (9.0 / 5.0) * celsius + 32;
    }

    public static double ToCelsius(double fahrenheit)
    {
        return (5.0 / 9.0) * (fahrenheit - 32);
    }
}
```

sample usage:

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "celsius to fahrenheit")
{
    label3.Text = TemperatureConverter.ToFahrenheit(input);
}
else if (comboBox1.Text == "fahrenheit to celsius")
{
    label3.Text = TemperatureConverter.ToCelsius(input);
}
```

Comment: Also 9.0 / 5.0 and 5.0 / 9.0 should be calculated manually and defined as constants.

Comment: @Alexander Compiler will do that for you, imo.